# Implementing Experience Optimization on top of website build in sdl web8.1.1 and DXA 1.6

Tags: web8, dxa, experience-optimization, personalization

I am looking for a some documentation that can help me to play with some basic personalization implementation on the website which is build on sdl web8.1.1 and DXA 1.6. I need some basic examples of personalization implementation that can give a general idea for sequence of steps/actions to do in web8-CME , fredhopper, website code.

At present i have found below DXA 1.6 XO module url which has a very limited details covering PT and Region names; and not one complete sequence of steps for any given example.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-B1678B63-477A-4D1F-9B03-5B87BD865CDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for general information on how Experience Optimization works, you should read the Experience Optimization docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-9931CB12-6060-42B5-BB31-BCA3DDD17BB1

Note that the DXA XO Module currently only supports XO Promotions and Content Experiments (not XO Navigation).

Comment: Hi Rick; I am trying to display one promotion on the webpage; since the website is build on top of DXA 1.6 should I only use the steps mentioned under DXA XO implementation guide. Or I need to follow the steps mentioned in XO implementation guide for promotion which ask to add below TBBs in PT 1)Add Promotions TBB 2)Add Experience Optimization Query 3)Apply Experience Optimization Settings.

Comment: You only need the steps mentioned in the DXA XO implementation guide.

Comment: Hi Rick Promotion not getting displayed; I am following the steps as per DXA XO implementation guide ; separate query raised for same here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16279/promotion-not-getting-displayed-on-webpage-using-experience-optimization-module

Answer (score 0):

To implement Personalization, say to display Promotion on webpage DXA 1.6 XO module implementation guide is sufficient. Need not to add any TBB in the PT which are mentioned in XO implementation guide (if using non DXA Environment). So it makes it more simpler if using DXA framework based website.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-B1678B63-477A-4D1F-9B03-5B87BD865CDF