# Promotion not getting displayed on webpage using Experience Optimization module for DXA 1.6

Tags: dxa, experience-optimization, dxa-1.6, personalization

I am using the steps mentioned in DXA XO implementation guide to display the promotion on the webpage. I have installed the DXA XO module in cms and website:

1)I am using XO Region Name="Example1" and RegionView="SmartTargetRegion" in my PT and CT both.

2)In CMS have created Promotion where Region defined as "Example1". and for content to use for promotion have added the component(using custom schema) mapped with dynamic CT.

3)On my webapplication page view when I am making call to the Region "Example1" using @Html.DxaRegion("Example1") it execute the Region View "SmartTargetRegion" but did not find any promotion content to render here. @Model.HasSmartTargetContent display False.it seems webpage not even make a query to promotional content

**MY custom PT snapshot Below:**
[image]

**My Custom CT (Promotion Content CT) below:**
[image]

**JSON response when page url hit with ?format=json below:**

```
{
   "$id":"1",
   "Regions":[
      {
         "$id":"2",
         "HasSmartTargetContent":false,
         "MaxItems":0,
         "Entities":[

         ],
         "Regions":[

         ],
         "Name":"Example1",
         "MvcData":{
            "$id":"3",
            "ControllerName":"Region",
            "ControllerAreaName":"Core",
            "ActionName":"Region",
            "ViewName":"SmartTargetRegion",
            "AreaName":"SmartTarget"
         }
      },
      {
         "$id":"4",
         "Entities":[
            {
               "$id":"5",
               "InfoText":"Showing Information For ",
               "SelectorList":[
                  {
                     "$id":"6",
                     "CssClassName":"state_selector",
                     "Contentlist":[
                        {
                           "$id":"7",
                           "LabelText":"California",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"8",
                              "LabelText":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:contentlist[1]/custom:labeltext"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"9",
                           "LabelText":"Florida",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"10",
                              "LabelText":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:contentlist[2]/custom:labeltext"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"11",
                           "LabelText":"Texas",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"12",
                              "LabelText":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:contentlist[3]/custom:labeltext"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"13",
                           "LabelText":"Other States",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"14",
                              "LabelText":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:contentlist[4]/custom:labeltext"
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                        "$id":"15",
                        "CssClassName":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:title",
                        "Contentlist":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:contentlist"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "$id":"16",
                     "CssClassName":"language_selector",
                     "Contentlist":[
                        {
                           "$id":"17",
                           "LabelText":"English",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"18",
                              "LabelText":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[2]/custom:contentlist[1]/custom:labeltext"
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                        "$id":"19",
                        "CssClassName":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[2]/custom:title",
                        "Contentlist":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[2]/custom:contentlist"
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "Id":"1422",
               "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                  "$id":"20",
                  "InfoText":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:info_text",
                  "SelectorList":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size"
               },
               "MvcData":{
                  "$id":"21",
                  "ControllerName":"Entity",
                  "ControllerAreaName":"Core",
                  "ActionName":"Entity",
                  "ViewName":"HeaderTopView",
                  "AreaName":"MyTestPOC",
                  "RegionName":"Header",
                  "RegionAreaName":"MyTestPOC"
               },
               "XpmMetadata":{
                  "$id":"22",
                  "ComponentID":"tcm:15-1422",
                  "ComponentModified":"2016-12-16T03:10:21",
                  "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:15-1423-32",
                  "ComponentTemplateModified":"2016-11-28T04:09:17",
                  "IsRepositoryPublished":false
               }
            },
            {
               "$id":"23",
               "Logo":{
                  "$id":"24",
                  "Url":"/media/MyTestLogo_tcm15-1441.png",
                  "FileName":"MyTestLogo.png",
                  "FileSize":17434,
                  "MimeType":"image/png",
                  "IsEmbedded":false,
                  "Id":"1441",
                  "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                     "$id":"25"
                  },
                  "MvcData":{
                     "$id":"26",
                     "ViewName":"Image",
                     "AreaName":"Core"
                  }
               },
               "Search":"Search",
               "Go":"Go",
               "Sitemap":"Sitemap",
               "SignIn":"Sign In",
               "Register":"Register",
               "Id":"1419",
               "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                  "$id":"27",
                  "Logo":"tcm:Content/custom:Header/custom:logo",
                  "Search":"tcm:Content/custom:Header/custom:search",
                  "Go":"tcm:Content/custom:Header/custom:go",
                  "Sitemap":"tcm:Content/custom:Header/custom:sitemap",
                  "SignIn":"tcm:Content/custom:Header/custom:signin",
                  "Register":"tcm:Content/custom:Header/custom:register"
               },
               "MvcData":{
                  "$id":"28",
                  "ControllerName":"Entity",
                  "ControllerAreaName":"Core",
                  "ActionName":"Entity",
                  "ViewName":"HeaderMain",
                  "AreaName":"MyTestPOC",
                  "RegionName":"Header",
                  "RegionAreaName":"MyTestPOC"
               },
               "XpmMetadata":{
                  "$id":"29",
                  "ComponentID":"tcm:15-1419",
                  "ComponentModified":"2016-11-30T04:56:14",
                  "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:15-1418-32",
                  "ComponentTemplateModified":"2016-11-28T03:08:17",
                  "IsRepositoryPublished":false
               }
            },
            {
               "$id":"30",
               "Components":[
                  {
                     "$id":"31",
                     "Title":"Become a Member",
                     "UrlLink":"/ca/en/becomeamember",
                     "UrlList":[
                        {
                           "$id":"32",
                           "LinkLabel":"Medi-Cal",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"33",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[1]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[1]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[1]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"34",
                           "LinkLabel":"Medicare",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"35",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[2]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[2]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[2]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"36",
                           "LinkLabel":"MyTest Dual Options Cal MediConnect Plan (Medicare-Medicaid Plan)",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"37",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[3]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[3]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[3]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"38",
                           "LinkLabel":"Covered California - MyTest Marketplace",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"39",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[4]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[4]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks[4]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                        "$id":"40",
                        "Title":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:title",
                        "UrlLink":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:urlLink",
                        "UrlList":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[1]/custom:listoflinks"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "$id":"41",
                     "Title":"Members",
                     "UrlLink":"/ca/en/memberlogin",
                     "UrlList":[
                        {
                           "$id":"42",
                           "LinkLabel":" Medi-Cal",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"43",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[1]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[1]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[1]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"44",
                           "LinkLabel":"Medicare",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"45",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[2]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[2]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[2]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"46",
                           "LinkLabel":"MyTest Dual Options Cal MediConnect Plan (Medicare-Medicaid Plan)",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"47",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[3]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[3]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[3]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"48",
                           "LinkLabel":"Covered California - MyTest Marketplace",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"49",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[4]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[4]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[4]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"50",
                           "LinkLabel":"Staying Healthy",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"51",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[5]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[5]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[5]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "$id":"52",
                           "LinkLabel":"My MyTest Portal",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                              "$id":"53",
                              "LinkLabel":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[6]/custom:linklabel",
                              "LinkUrl":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[6]/custom:linkurl",
                              "LinkType":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks[6]/custom:displaychoice"
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
                        "$id":"54",
                        "Title":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:title",
                        "UrlLink":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:urlLink",
                        "UrlList":"tcm:Content/custom:LinkChain/custom:linkchainlist[2]/custom:listoflinks"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "$id":"55",
                     "Title":"Health Care Professionals",
                     "UrlList":[
                        {
                           "$id":"56",
                           "LinkLabel":"Medicare",
                           "LinkUrl":"#",
                           "LinkType":"Link",
                           "XpmPropertyMetadata":{
```

**Website Logs below:**

```
2017-01-13 05:44:13,745 [1] INFO  - -------- Initializing DXA Framework v1.6.0.223 --------
2017-01-13 05:44:13,874 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.DefaultCacheProvider' for interface ICacheProvider.
2017-01-13 05:44:13,876 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider' for interface IContentProvider.
2017-01-13 05:44:13,877 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.StaticNavigationProvider' for interface INavigationProvider.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,329 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider' for interface IContextClaimsProvider.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,331 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Linking.DefaultLinkResolver' for interface ILinkResolver.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,332 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor' for interface IRichTextProcessor.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,332 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IConditionalEntityEvaluator.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,334 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper' for interface IMediaHelper.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,337 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver' for interface ILocalizationResolver.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,338 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.BaseStaticFileManager' for interface IStaticFileManager.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,339 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IUnknownLocalizationHandler.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,876 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ItemList' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,877 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,877 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ItemListElements' as semantic property 's:itemListElement'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,878 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article' has semantic type(s) 's:Article'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,879 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,879 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,880 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Date' as semantic property 's:dateCreated'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,880 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:about'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,881 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ArticleBody' as semantic property 's:articleBody'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,882 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Download' has semantic type(s) 's:DataDownload s:MediaObject'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,883 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:name s:description'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,883 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,884 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,886 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image' has semantic type(s) 's:ImageObject s:MediaObject'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,886 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'AlternateText' as semantic property 's:name'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,887 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,887 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,889 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Place' has semantic type(s) 's:Place'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,889 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Name' as semantic property 's:name'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,890 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,891 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Address' as semantic property 's:address'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,891 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Telephone' as semantic property 's:telephone'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,892 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FaxNumber' as semantic property 's:faxNumber'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,892 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Email' as semantic property 's:email'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,893 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Location' as semantic property 's:geo'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,894 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.YouTubeVideo' has semantic type(s) 's:VideoObject s:MediaObject'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,894 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,895 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,896 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Teaser, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,897 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,898 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,898 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,910 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Site.Areas.Test.Models.MyItem' has semantic type(s) 's:MyItemSample'.
2017-01-13 05:44:17,910 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'name' as semantic property 's:name'
2017-01-13 05:44:17,911 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'description' as semantic property 's:description'
2017-01-13 05:44:18,276 [7] WARN  - HTML design is not published nor does file 'D:\Jhalender\GTDevelopment\src\Site\system\assets\version.json' exist on disk. Setting version to v0.0
2017-01-13 05:44:18,353 [7] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/config/_all.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-13 05:44:18,831 [7] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/config/core.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-13 05:44:18,850 [7] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://localhost:92/ca/en/landing' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-13 05:44:20,006 [7] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/mappings/includes.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-13 05:44:20,144 [7] ERROR - Could not load file or assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4450e3c7f68bf872' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4450e3c7f68bf872' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4450e3c7f68bf872'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline..cctor()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

2017-01-13 05:44:20,146 [7] WARN  - An error occurred while initializing the Model Builder Pipeline. Using the Default Model Builder.
2017-01-13 05:44:20,199 [7] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/mappings/schemas.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-13 05:44:20,249 [7] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/mappings/vocabularies.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-13 05:44:20,285 [7] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-13 05:44:20,307 [7] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-13 05:44:20,311 [7] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-13 05:44:20,312 [7] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-13 05:44:20,313 [7] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema
```

Comment: Enable DEBUG (or maybe even TRACE) level logging and check the DXA log file.

Comment: Hi Rick; when you say DXA log do you mean website log please confirm

Comment: @RickPannekoek; I found that SmartTargetRegion View use  @Html.Raw(Model.GetStartQueryXpmMarkup()) but its not generating any markup on the webpage when i see the viewsource of the page. I think thats the reason no query fired by webpage to request promotion. Is there any reason for same ? Do I missing anything in PT or Page in CMS ?

Comment: Please check you DXA log ("website log" if you wish; I mean the file which is configured in `Log.config`).  You can also try to retrieve the Page with `?format=json` in the URL;  I'm curious how the `XpmMetadata` of the ST Region looks in the JSON.

Comment: @RickPannekoek; page url with ?format=json shows {"$id":"1","Regions":[{"$id":"2","HasSmartTargetContent":false,"MaxItems":0,"Entities":[],"Regions":[],"Name":"Example1","MvcData":{"$id":"3","ControllerName":"Region","ControllerAreaName":"Core","ActionName":"Region","ViewName":"SmartTargetRegion","AreaName":"SmartTarget"}},{"$id":"4","Entities":

Comment: No `XpmMetadata` at all? That implies your website is not XPM-enabled (check `BinaryData\<pubId>\system\config\_all.json`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51659/discussion-between-gulshan-thakur-and-rick-pannekoek).

Comment: @RickPannekoek; Entire content not pasted earlier; There are XPMMetadata details also:
[{"$id":"7","LabelText":"California","XpmPropertyMetadata":{"$id":"8","LabelText‌​":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:contentlist[1]/cust‌​om:labeltext"}},{"$id":"9","LabelText":"Florida","XpmPropertyMetadata":{"$id":"10‌​","LabelText":"tcm:Content/custom:TopRowHeader/custom:type_size[1]/custom:content‌​list[2]/custom:labeltext"}},

Comment: website is XPM enabled and we are able to edit the webpage content using XPM editing tool directly on browser

Comment: Can you please update the Question and provide the complete JSON (formatted, please) of the ST Region; I want to see the `XpmMetadata` (not `XpmPropertyMetadata`) of the ST Region. Please also provide info about what is in the log file.

Comment: Oh, BTW: what the first JSON fragment does show is that `MaxItems = 0`. That is unexpected (since your CM screenshot shows `3`).

Comment: @RickPannekoek; Json response and Website logs added in Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let me walk you through the analysis of the artifacts you provided:

The JSON reveals two issues:

- There is no `XpmMetadata` at all for the ST Region. That explains why `Model.GetStartQueryMarkup` is empty. This is unexpected, because XPM is enabled (as witnessed by `XpmMetadata` on some Entities furtheron).
- `MaxItems` is `0` whereas you would expect `3`.

The DXA log file also reveals two issues:

- The HTML Design is not published from CM-side, nor does a `version.json` file exist in order to create versioned URLs.
- Initialization of the DXA Model Builder Pipeline failed because DD4T 2.1.0.0 assemblies could not be loaded (!)

Obviously, the last issue is a very severe one which is the root cause of your problem.

Most likely, you are trying to use DXA XO Module v1.7 in combination with the DXA Framework v1.6. Indeed, DXA XO Module v1.7 uses DD4T 2.1 (and so does DXA Framework v1.7), but DXA Framework v1.6 uses DD4T 2.0.

So: you should either use DXA XO Module v1.6 (see https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/releases ) or upgrade your DXA Framework to v1.7 (see http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-7BBD251F-E5AB-4A40-B57A-51E3F7635C17 ).

Lesson learned (I hope): if things don't work, **always** check your DXA log file and check for WARNings and ERRORs. Especially ERRORs should never be ignored. If you create a Question, always include such important information from the log file.

Comment: Yes Rick you are right; I refer  DXA 1.6 impl guide that contain link to download DXA XO Module and instead of 1.6 it download 1.7; Now to remove 1.7 and install 1.6 what should be the approach; is there any commands to uninstall DXA XO module 1.7

Comment: You don't have to uninstall 1.7, just install 1.6 and it will replace 1.7.

Comment: For other two points 1) HTML Design not published - I have not created any HTML Design item in CMS, And are created at Web Application end. Thus have not publish it. 2)version.json file - do i need to publish any specific item from CMS for this ?

Comment: You can make the HTML Design part of the Web App, but you should then also put a `Version.json` file in the Web App (you can see the path where DXA expects it in the log file). This allows you to version the HTML design: as soon as you change the version number in `Version.json`, the URLs of all HTML Design assets change forcing browsers to retrieve the new version rather than cached versions. The contents of the file should be `{ "version": "x.y" }`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rick Many Thanks for your help to debug the issue and pointing to root cause.

**Root Cause of Issue :** Installed DXA XO Module version was 1.7 and DXA Framework version was 1.6; When I re-install DXA XO Module 1.6 version it works perfectly fine.

Installation of dxa xo module 1.6 (both on cms and website) automatically over-rides dxa xo module 1.7 so no need to do an explicit uninstall for dxa xo module 1.7 version.